# Alerts on Document Library filter by user

Tags: document-library, alert, filter

I copy folders and documents to a document library by code through a feature.
I am trying to prevent alerts from being fired when the document library is populated.

I tried setting the Filter property as follow :

```
newAlert.Filter = string.Format("<Query><Neq><FieldRef Name=\"Author\"/><Value type=\"string\">{0}</Value></Neq></Query>", "SHAREPOINT\\system");
```

But it doesn't work , alerts keep on being triggered.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your caml query seems not correct. Recheck it via googling. As Author field will be of type Person and It should be CreatedBy maybe!

Comment: The correct way of filtering on user Column is :                newAlert.Filter = "<Query><Neq><FieldRef Name=\"Author/New\"  /><Value type=\"Text\">" + userFilter + "</Value></Neq></Query>";

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of filtering on user Column is :

```
newAlert.Filter = "<Query><Neq><FieldRef Name=\"Author/New\" /><Value type=\"Text\">" + userFilter + "</Value></Neq></Query>"
```

where userFilter if the loginname

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Make a console application with the following code to Disable/Enable alerts on a SharePoint 2010/2007 list/Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80475/sharepoint-2010-how-to-temporarily-disable-alerts-being-sent-for-a-document-li)?

Comment: I don't think so, the filter is for triggering or not the alert : http://dormantdevelopment.com/wordpress/index.php/2011/07/17/making-sharepoint-alerts-programmatically/